# Why the .config file doesn't works for me

Tags: ros, message, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu: 12.04

ROS: Hydro

I am learning to set the level of logging message, however, I find that my .config doesn't work.

This is my source code in `example1.cpp`:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  ros::init( argc, argv, "example1" );
  //ROS_DEBUG( "This is a DEBUG message!" );   
 ROS_INFO("This is an INFO message!");
 ROS_WARN("This is a WARN message!");
 ROS_ERROR("This is an ERROR message!");
 ROS_FATAL("This is a FATAL message!");

 ros::spinOnce();
 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

`chapter3_tutorials.config`:

```
log4j.logger.ros.chapter3_tutorials.config=ERROR
```

`example1.launch` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch>
  <!-- Logger config -->
  <env name="ROSCONSOLE_CONFIG_FILE"
       value="$(find chapter3_tutorials)/config/chapter3_tutorials.config"/>

  <!-- Example 1 -->
  <node pkg="chapter3_tutorials" type="example1" name="example1"
        output="screen"/>
</launch>
```

After I `roslaunch` the code, it should print only logging message **ERROR** and **FATAL**,
But the **INFO** and **WARN** also are printed.

How to solve it?
Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221315/why-the-.config-file-doesn%27t-works-for-me/) by [ChenJinluo](https://answers.ros.org/users/24992/chenjinluo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2015-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like there is one "config" too much, try this:

```
log4j.logger.ros.chapter3_tutorials=ERROR
```

---

Originally posted by [Philipp Schillinger](https://answers.ros.org/users/24945/philipp-schillinger/) with karma: 321 on 2015-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChenJinluo](https://answers.ros.org/users/24992/chenjinluo/) on 2015-11-21**:
Oh, I was stupid. Thank you very much!~